# nginx - Redirect to urls without extension and add slash at the end

Tags: nginx, redirect, server, nginx-config

Using nginx, I would like to redirect all my static html URLs( mydomain.com/index.html; mydomain.com/contact.html; mydomain.com/about.html ) to the same urls without extension but with a slash at the end.

The end urls should be like that:

mydomain.com/index/

mydomain.com/contact/

mydomain.com/about/
....

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if you'd have both `/.../webroot/route.html` file and `/.../webroot/route/` folder? Which one should be prefered?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this question. The first is how to make the server return `contact.html` in response to the URI `/contact/`.

There are a number of ways to achieve this. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/.+)/$ $1.html last;
    return 404;
}
```

Any URI ending with a `/` will be internally mapped to the same URI with the `/` replaced by `.html`.

---

The second part is if people are still accessing the `.html` URIs using the old scheme, you may want to externally redirect them to the new scheme.

The best way to achieve this without creating a redirection loop, is to check the original request stored in `$request_uri`. For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\.html(?|$)") {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.html $1/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard,  thanks a lot, it works for the home page, and on the sub pages, but on the sub-pages I have the problem that the css and js files are not loaded, because the path for it (for example) is considered as a subfolder. Any solution for that?

Comment: I think your saying you have relative URIs for the resource files, and now that you have added a `/`, the browser is asking for the wrong URL. This isn't really an Nginx problem. If you want to use relative URIs in your applications you should perhaps consider using `/contact` rather than `/contact/`.

Comment: Hi, for SEO purposes, I have to add a trailing slash at the end of the urls.